# Sass stylesheet is not being loaded - webpack

Tags: sass, styles, webpack

I have a single style.scss files which imported other stylesheets. What I want to achieve is

1. Load the style on my page
2. Watch any changes on the all stylesheet files for changes and reflect it live on the browser (without clicking on refresh button).

I am using webpack-dev-server to serve files. However I cannot see the style applied to my page.

Here is my loader in webpack config:

```
modules: {
      loaders: [ 
          {
             test: /\.scss$/,
             loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader")
          }
      ]
},
plugin: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
]
```

and in my entry point file which is main.js I have

```
require('../scss/style.scss');
```

When I run webpack the style.css is created correctly. However when I run the app using webpack-dev-server I cannot see style applied.

You can find the code on [Github](https://github.com/neginbasiri/webpack.git)

Can someone please help to find what's the issue?

Comment: you have used ExtractTextPlugin in loader so i don't think that you need it to be declared in plugin.. i'm cloning your repo to look into.

Comment: @MrJSingh I'd appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by removing "ExtractTextPlugin" from plugins and changing loader

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
  }
```

This works for development. For prod I still need ExtractTextPlugin to create styles.css

Comment: Yes that i noticed yesterday but i didn't had the time to share with you. I believe there is a issue with ExtractTextPlugin but i saw many people using it so it must be with the newer version.